# How to get back missing grub2 menu after boot-repair

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, grub-efi

I have a dual boot system in UEFI mode with Windows 7(x64) on sda3 and Ubuntu 18 on sda5 in ext4 filesystem. Earlier Ubuntu was booting with grub2 but now grub menu is not there. It is just blank.

[Boot Repair Logs](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9DTr46dsms/)

Comment: Can you boot Windows directly from UEFI boot menu. Grub only boots working Windows, so if Windows has issues both grub will not boot it and os-prober will not find it. Even the entries that Boot-Repair added will not normally boot Windows but UEFI direct boot (and maybe f8 for repairs) should work. Otherwise you may need a Windows repair disk. And if os-prober does not find another system, it default boots to only choice or Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes win7x64 boots fine from the uefi bios

Comment: When you say grub menu is 'blank', do you get a grub prompt (black background) or is it just a plain plum background with no boot options?

Comment: no grub the menu doesnt load

Answer (score 1):

solved: the menu is presented but there is a blank purple covering page that needs a Press Esc key that closes the 'ghost' page so I can see the grub2 menu. There is no ubuntu logo on the ghost cover page. I wonder does anyone know how to get rid of that ghost page. Thanks for all your answers.